# AJAX wait until file exist on another server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a website based in to servers. One is a free host and another is a Raspberry Pi. When you access a webpage in the free host, you get a form where you enter a link. The link is send to the Raspberry Pi which is permanently running a script that downloads some content of the link recieved and saves a big txt file. The script takes a bit to load (30 secs aprox) so I want to create a Javascript script in the primary page (free host one, with the form) wich shows a load icon and checks in the raspberry downloads folder until the file exists.

I think AJAX will be the best for this. The workflow is:

user access form.php and enters a link
the form is send directly to the RPi
the RPi begins to download things and returns the user to the refferrer page with the get parameter id=
**here the ajax code begins to work checks into an url if .txt exists if it exists, it shows the download link else, it waits checking until it gets a 200 status code** (This is what i need)

I know the problem with javascript and different servers so i've created a php script named check.php in the same server and folder of form.php which gets id as parameter and return 200 or 404 so the ajax code just needs to get that answer and act in consecuence

How can I do it? I'm new to AJAX, I know just a bit of Javascript. Could you help me withe the AJAX code?

My form.php?id= page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
 <? 
 if (!$_GET){ 
 ?> 
  <form action="<<rpi server>>" method="post">
   URL: <input type="text" name="link">
   <input type="submit" value="Download">
  </form>
 <? 
 }else{
  ?>
  <script>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/check.php',
    data: {'id':'<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>'},
    //check if response is 200 or 404, if it's 404 keep checking every second, else show mesage
    }
 });
        </script>
        <?
 }
 ?>

 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
function checkFile()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/check.php',
        data: {'id':'999'},
        error : function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ checkFile(); }, 3000);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            //do whatever you want
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    checkFile();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just had to modify the check.php file to return a 404 error if the file doesn't exists.